# how does this for loop works in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, range, jupyter

So I'm learning this for loops in jupyter notebook, and  I was told to print the apple once, banana twice and republic three times, here's the code: (it's correct)

```
a = ["apple", "banana", "republic" ]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
         print(a[i])
```

so the point is, i dont understand how this code works, like what does the 'i' and 'j' stands for. can anyone pls help, thanks!

Comment: In each of your loops add `print(i)` and `print(j)` respectively, or use an IDE such as PyCharm, VSCode, etc.

Comment: It looks like i is the index taken from list a. But I'm not sure why you don't just iterate through list using for i in a.

Comment: It works the same way as in any other Python environment. If you wrote the code yourself and don't understand it, I don't know how anyone else is supposed to be able to help you with that. If you generally don't understand the syntax of for loops, perhaps you should review your textbook, or whatever other source you are using to learn Python.

Comment: i did not write the code, i got it from YT. i'm learning python from yt and they gave me that code, if i wrote it, i wouldn't ask this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fruit` here is assigned each of the values in `fruits`; hence the `fruit in fruits`.

`print(fruit)` will be executed once per item in the `fruits` list, each time with `fruit` assigned to the next value in the list starting at the first.

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'republic']

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit)

apple
banana
republic
```

You can use the `enumerate` function to get a tuple containing not only the `fruit` variable as above, but also the index in the `fruits` list.

```py
for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    print(idx, fruit)

0 apple
1 banana
2 republic
```

The `range` function helps you run a for loop over the `idx` variable value (+ 1, since `idx` starts at `0`). It essentially gives you something akin to a list (called an iterator), in this case `[0] [0, 1] [0, 1, 2]` but the actual values are irrelevant for us.

```py
for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    for _ in range(idx + 1):
        print(fruit)

apple
banana
banana
republic
republic
republic
```

Check the code at [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/178D3-4VS9wt24QFPw5YuqHC6ZdBHJJHf?usp=sharing).

*Note. `_` is a convention for a variable name that will not be used.*

Answer (score 0):

In python, loops are foreach Like loops so when youCall range(number) function it create a generator (which is iterable)  the (when casting to list) looks like so:

```
 print(list(range(3)))
 >> [0,1,2]
```

And the values of j is iterating throw those number so for example the inner loop in the second iteration in the third iteration of the outer loops thvales are

```
i=2
j=1
```

And the len function is returning a number representing the length pf the list

Answer (score 0):

> *The most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled with judiciously placed print statements.*
> — Brian Kernighan, Unix for Beginners

Add `print` statements in the code until you understand what's going on.

```py
a = ["apple", "banana", "republic" ]
print('len(a): ', len(a))
for i in range(len(a)):
    print('i: ', i, '; for j in range(', i+1, ')')
    for j in range(i + 1):
         print('j: ', j)
         print(a[i])
```

Now run it and see what it's doing.